# ¿Porque un input me sale "undefined" y el otro me da el valor cuando se lo pido?

Tags: reactjs, input, querystring

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Unirse.css";

const Unirse = () => {
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState("");
  const [sala, setSala] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="sala__box">
      <div className="sala__main">
        <h1 className="sala__heading">Unirse</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setUsuario(e.target.value)}
          className="sala__input mb-20"
          placeholder="Elija un nick..."
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setSala(e.target.value)}
          className="sala__input  mb-20"
          placeholder="Nombre su server..."
        ></input>
        <Link
          to={`/server?name=${usuario}&sala=${sala}`}
          onClick={(e) => (!usuario || !sala ? e.preventDefault() : null)}
        >
          <button type="submit" className="sala__btn ">
            Logearse
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Unirse;
```

---

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import queryString from "query-string";

const Sala = ({ location }) => {
  location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    const { usuario, sala } = queryString.parse(location.search);
    console.log(usuario, sala); // no me lee usuario(error!)
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sala</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sala;
```

**Estoy haciendo una CHAT-APP con socket.
Me está pasando algo realmente raro, cuando pongo los valores y envío mis datos, no se me lee en consola el primer input.
Y si me lee el primer valor del input en mi query-string, por eso no entiendo.
Como ven ambas configuraciones de mis inputs son iguales, y al retornar me devuelve el primer input *undefined* y el otro su valor**

Comment: Tu estás intentando sacar `usuario` de la url... Pero según veo tu código, la url a la que mandas tiene un `name` y un `sala`... no un `usuario`... por eso debe salir undefined

Comment: Gracias @Pipe, era eso! Me salvaste! Buena semana para vos!